# Migration error: Unknown column 'rawpassword' in 'field list'

Tags: migration

I have tred to migrate a website in Joomla from 1.5 to 2.5 using jUpgrade but I have receive the "undefined migrating" error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unknown
>   column 'rawpassword' in 'field list' SQL=INSERT INTO `j25_users`
>   (`id`,`name`,`username`,`email`,`password`,`rawpassword`,`usertype`,`block`,`sendEmail`,`registerDate`,`lastvisitDate`,`activation`,`params`,`newsletter`,`blog`)
>   VALUES
>   ('62','Administrator','idnadmin','webmaster@example.com','a67042770b2ebf18e330abbef9453a06:LKQiBAD5PjxFacEoXzHLSV7uhIAEfNGX','','Super
>   Administrator','0','1','2011-06-09 23:43:07','2014-07-07
>   04:17:19','66b5d829f602c13165caecbe88d4f19f:RDRr56vAoRMkaVaQUnjRacD1xiCkDNgM','{\"admin_language\""\",\"language\""\",\"editor\""\",\"helpsite\""\",\"timezone\""UTC\"}','0','1')'
>   in
>   /home/tesit126/public_html/wm/administrator/components/com_jupgrade/includes/jupgrade.class.php:347
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/tesit126/public_html/wm/administrator/components/com_jupgrade/includes/controller.php(45):
>   jUpgrade->upgrade() #1 {main} thrown in
>   /home/tesit126/public_html/wm/administrator/components/com_jupgrade/includes/jupgrade.class.php
>   on line 347
>   ========== [undefined] [undefined]

Any ideas

Comment: Where did you get the `rawpassword` column from? This is not a standard Joomla column in the `#__users` table. Did you add that in yourself?

Answer (score 1):

The rawpassword field doesn't even exist in that table. In any case, you can solve the problem by just adding a rawpassword field (VARCHAR 255) to the #__users table.

Comment: yes, it does exist, it just has no value